# Automatic Vertical Scrolling of a TextView So The Last line Added Is Always Shown?

Tags: android

I have a TextView which I will add various lines of text to. I have placed the TextView within a ScrollView to allow USER scrolling of the TextView however I want the TextView when it is full of text to automatically scroll up when another line is added.

I cannot find any solutions to this. Ther must be a way of automatically scrolling a TextView vertically. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to do it in a TextView but you can use a ListView with `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"` and `android:stackFromBottom="true"` to get that desired behaviour. See this [Google IO talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) at around 32 min.

Comment: Handy link Noel (for future reference) but I don't think ListView is suitable for my aim. I'm aiming for a 'command line' much like a terminal in Linux.